# Sending Intent inside of another Intent

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, android-widget

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, but I want to respond to my Android AppWidget's click event within my own app AND launch an Activity. At the time I set the `PendingIntent` I have another `Intent` which I want to launch when clicked. My `onStartCommand` uses this line:

```
final Intent mLaunchIntent = (Intent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Widget.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

When I call `setOnClickPendingIntent` I have this line prior:

```
mSendingIntent.putExtra(Widget.EXTRA_INTENT, (Parcelable) mLaunchIntent);
```

So even though `mLaunchIntent` is a valid `Intent` in both lines, the first line is missing a great deal of data. Calling `startActivity` then fails because the `Intent` is not valid.

I am wondering if it is possible, and how, to send an `Intent` inside of another `Intent` without strictly calling `putExtras` because that method simple adds the extras from one `Intent` to the next. I'd like to keep these two separate and easily accessible.

Answer (score 13):

I actually figured it out, the solution was quite simple. `mLaunchIntent` should not be cast to `Parcelable` or the data gets lost.

```
mSendingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mLaunchIntent);
```

That was all that I needed to send an `Intent` through another `Intent`.

Comment: There Should Be `Intent.EXTRA_INTENT` instead of `Widget.EXTRA_INTENT`

Comment: can you please tell ,how to retrieve the intent and pass to intent object

Answer (score 7):

You can put an Intent to an Intent with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent());
```

To retrieve the Intent (from within an Activity) from the intent you can do the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a `service` to parse the Intent?

Comment: I am using a Service, but that Service gets called with an Intent, in this case `mSendingIntent`. I need to pass `mLaunchIntent` alongside that Intent so that the click event then launches an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can pass intents / objects from source to destination and vice versa. One way of doing it without using bundles or extras would be resorting to the usual class methods with variables (getters and setters). Pass the objects using methods. Another way of doing it would be the use of class variables. Ex:

```
public class ClassB  extends Activity{
    public static Object myObject;
    ...
}

public class ClassA extends Activity{
    ...
    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Object myObject = ClassB.myObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's... one solution. But that fails in my case because of a number of issues. For one, what if the user clicked two widgets in sequence. I don't want to modify a global variable or have to set up some sort of global queue. Also, the Service and BroadcastReceiver operate on different Threads. Race conditions make this a very tricky solution.