# Send and get Intent from another intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My question is very simple. I want to send from an activity (A) an intent that containing another intent and retrive data on activity (B).

I look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381535/sending-intent-inside-of-another-intent#answer-13384433), but is not explained how get information.

EDIT:
For better comprehension, I get this intent result from ActivityResult and i want to pass it to another. I post the code:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,RoomActivity.class);
        //How to put the extra data intent?
        startActivity(i);
       //How get data in RoomActivity ?
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass information from one activity to another?

Comment: No, i get an intent result from onActivityResult, and i want to pass to another activity,

Comment: Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, just added

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is not the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a pojo class to save your data and make it Parcelable then putExtra("yourKey",dataObject) in Activity A.
Use getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("yourkey") to get your object in Activity B.

Comment: I thought to this solution, but i want to avoid because i need many field from this intent and not all of this are Parcelable